jQuery scroll function working in chrome, but not safari on Wordpress website
I've just started working in a new website, built by someone else but now I'm taking over. For the header menu, there is a jquery event that when the user scrolls down, new classes are added to the header menu, and new styles are applied. It's working perfectly fine in chrome, but it's not working at all in safari. The event isn't triggering on scroll, no classes are being added. It's a wordpress website. Here is the code:
// Header menu tricks
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
jQuery('.header-area, .homepage-popup, #desktop-mini-cart').addClass('tight departed');
} else {
jQuery('.header-area, .homepage-popup, #desktop-mini-cart').removeClass('tight');
}
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
jQuery('.menu-display-area').addClass('tight');
} else {
jQuery('.menu-display-area').removeClass('tight');
}
});
});

And when I inspect the console in safari, I get this error: Failed to load resource: You do not have permission to access the requested resource.
Does anyone know why this would be working in chrome, and not safari? Anything about how to grand access? If you want to see for yourself, here is the website: https://www.ashleybottendesign.com/

It's working just fine in Safari... But why are you using two (document).ready closures and two (window).scroll closures where one of each would be sufficient?

jQuery(document).ready(function () {  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {   if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {    jQuery('.header-area, .homepage-popup, #desktop-mini-cart').addClass('tight departed');    jQuery('.menu-display-area').addClass('tight');   } else {    jQuery('.header-area, .homepage-popup, #desktop-mini-cart').removeClass('tight');    jQuery('.menu-display-area').removeClass('tight');   }  }); }); this much will work well. Remove the unnecessary duplicate code.

It's not working in older safari versions (I have version 15.6) even when I just use javascript, and I still can't figure out why. Those code changes don't help.
